# How to move all video files in all sub-directory to a parent directory?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

Best would be using a .bat file. But could also be Powershell if it's easier.

Now I'm using this:

```
for /r "M:\movies\new\" %%x in (*.mp4) do move "%%x" "M:\movies\new\"
```

but this works only for one extension (.mp4). How could I do this for multiple extensions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch move a folder's content up one level](https://superuser.com/questions/1115231/batch-move-a-folders-content-up-one-level)

Comment: You can put it like this `(*.*)` , right?

Comment: But there are also some .txt files in it which I don't want. :S

Comment: Use `*.*` and qualify the move statement: `... in (*.*) do if not %%~xx == .txt move ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows (and MacOS plus *ix) predate the numerous extensions created to hold video. The OS just doesn't know how to tell what is a video file and what isn't, so you will need to run that command line for each extension you wish to move.

Alternatively, move the *.txt files to another directory, move everything remaining, then move *.txt back, a la

```
for /r "M:\movies\new\" %%x in (*.txt) do move "%%x" "M:\placeholder\"
for /r "M:\movies\new\" %%x in (*.*) do move "%%x" "M:\movies\new\"
for /r "M:\placeholder\" %%x in (*.txt) do move "%%x" "M:\original directory\"
```